# Split on regex Python

Tags: python, regex, split

I feel stupid asking such a question, but I can't get it to work. I made a trivial regex to split strings with the following format :

```
(15,20) (17,30 )   ( 40 ,  25)
```

I voluntarily let random blanks because it is legal in the format. My regex is pretty basic : `[^0-9-]+`, and [works fine](http://regexr.com/3a5j9). I'm familiar enough with regexes in Java and Scala so I first checked the [doc of Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to see the differences and it seems this regex is correct though it could be shorter.

Yet, it does not split anything.

Code :

```
"(15,20) (17,30 )   ( 40 ,  25)".split("[^0-9-]+")
```

Output :

```
['(15,20) (17,30 )   ( 40 ,  25)']
```

Any idea why such a simple regex does not work ?

Comment: Please include your code. The pattern works - if you use it right.

Comment: Yes, I don't use it the same way, I had expected the split method on str would work the same way that on other languages I know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are **not using a regular expression method**. Use the [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html); the [`re.split()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) does what you want just fine:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'[^0-9]+', '(15,20) (17,30 )   ( 40 ,  25)')
['', '15', '20', '17', '30', '40', '25', '']
```

The [`str.split()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) doesn't take a regular expression.

Comment: @Dici: regular expressions are handled by a dedicated module so it can be maintained upgraded separately. A [new version](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) is being tested. Not all code needs the extra processing weight of regular expressions.